# How to make the text and checkbox in my div bold and light grey depending on check status

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I'm building a tables columns and rows with divs. For specific reasons and constructing it in Javascript like so

```
column.append('<div class="maRow"><label><input ' + IsChecked + ' type="checkbox" name="maCheckBox" data-parent=' + val.ParentID+ ' value=' + val.GroupNameID + '> ' + val.GroupName + '</label></div>');
```

Here is the rendered html for each row in the columns

```html
<div class="maRow">
  <label>
    <input checked="" type="checkbox" name="maCheckBox" data-parent="0" value="21312">Some Text</label>
</div>
```

What do I need to do so that I can set checked checkboxes w/ text to bold (default) and unchecked checkboxes w/ their text to light grey and not bold?

It looks like the font-weight is 700 for each label, so how would I change that based on whether the checkbox is checked or not?

Comment: are you trying something like this http://jsfiddle.net/vozpba1c/?

Answer (score 1):

Already answered in (probably) many posts, here is one, ([How to style checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css/4148544#4148544))

Use the css selector `input:checked{}` then apply styling to underlying elements

### HTML

```
<div class="maRow">
  <label>
    <input checked="" type="checkbox" name="maCheckBox" data-parent="0" value="21312"><span>Some Text</span></label>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.maRow input[type=checkbox] + span{
  font-weight:normal;
  color: gray;
}

.maRow input[type=checkbox]:checked + span{
  font-weight:bold;
  color:black;
}
```